# Delayed evaluation / references to atomic datatypes in data structures

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3, I use serialize data to JSON like so:

```
import json

config = {
   'server' : {
      'host' : '127.0.0.1',
      'port' : 12345
    }
}

serialized_config = json.dumps(config)
```

Due to `json.dumps` and the fact that the format of the JSON is fixed, I cannot alter the struct
of the python data arbitralily, e.g. `host` needs to be a string when `config` is passed to `json.dumps`. I cannot wrap it in a list like `'host' : ['1.1.1.1]'` e.g.

Now the data is way more complex than in this example, but mostly redundant (e.g. there is only one 'host' that is constant but appears in various places throughout the config.
Now I like to define some template like so:

```
template = {
   'server' : {
      'host' : SERVER_IP,
      'port' : 12345
   }
}
```

And afterwards replace all occurences of e.g. `SERVER_IP` with the actual server ip etc.
The point is that I don't know the value of `SERVER_IP` when I define the template.
The easy way would be to just shift the atomic string into a non-atomic python struct, e.g.:

```
server = {
    'host' : '1.1.1.1',
    'port' : 12345
}

template = {
   'server' : server
}

...

# Here the actual value of 'host' has been set
server['host'] = '192.168.0.1'

print(json.dumps(template))
```

This dumps

```
'{"server": {"host": "192.168.0.1", "port": 12345}}'
```

As wanted.

However, since `port` etc. also change, I would prefer something like (pseudo-code):

```
server_ip = '1.1.1.1' # not the actual value

template = {
   'server' : {
      'host' : ref(server_ip), # Don't copy the string, but either delay the evaluation or somehow create a ref to the string
      'port' : 12345
   }
}

...
server_ip = '192.168.0.1'
```

I am aware that I could write code that just traverses the python data and 'manually' replaces certain strings with different values.

However, I am curious if there is some better solution.

E.g. I played around with facilitating `__getattribute__` like so:

```
class DelayedEval:

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.data = d

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        # Recursive matters let aside for sake of simplicity...
        data = object.__getattribute__(self, 'data')
        v = data[key]
        try:
            v = v()
        except:
            pass
        return v

    # possibly overwrite __getitem__() etc as well ...

server_ip = '1.1.1.1'

template = {

    'server' : {
        'host' : lambda: server_ip, # prevents 'premature evalutation'
        'port' : 12345
    }
}

...

server_ip = '192.168.0.1'

print(json.dumps(DelayedEval(template))) # Does not work
```

I am *not* asking for fixing this code, I am asking for any solution that solves my issue, no matter how, as long as You deem it 'better' than the bute-force approach of traverse and replace manually.

Fixing this code might solve my problem, but there might be better solutions (or none?).

I am aware that this is a rather complicated question to pose, and probably for my usecase overly complex, however, I am curious whether there would be a viable solution to this problem apart from the brute-force 'search-and-replace' approach...

Is there some way to define 'self-completing template structs' like that in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy approach is to make the template itself a lambda function:

```
template = lambda: {
    'server' : {
        'host' : server_ip,
        'port' : 12345
    }
}

...

server_ip = '192.168.0.1'

print(json.dumps(template()))
```

Comment: That's a great solution, this simple that - in hindsight - I wonder how I could not have found it myself... Thanks a lot!

Comment: better yet: explicitely pass the ip (and other moving parts) as arguments to `template()`. Also, use a proper function instead of a lambda - lambdas are for anonymous functions.